# Integral of $\frac{1}{|x|}$ over a ball radius $R$ centered at $ x_0 $

Tags: integration, analysis, inequality

Suppose $ x_0\in B_R(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^2 $, $ \gamma\in (0,2) $.
Prove
$$\int_{B_R(0)}\frac{1}{|x-x_0|^\gamma}\mathrm{d} x<\int_{B_R(0)}\frac{1}{|x|^\gamma}\mathrm{d} x.$$
Can we compute $$\int_{B_R(0)}\frac{1}{|x-x_0|^\gamma}\mathrm{d} x$$
directly?

Comment: What is your space? $\mathbb R^{n}$?

Comment: Several related questions are already answered ; look for 'Related' column on the right panel of this  page.